# What is wrong with this audio in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html5-audio

I've been getting very angry at this HTML5 and audio stuff with JavaScript. It worked fine when it was already in HTML but since I moved it to JavaScript its just not working. I do not wish to use jQuery because I want to keep the size as low as possible.
All the functions do exist and same goes for the variables. Chrome isn't giving me any errors but **Chrome Developer tools under network says; pending**. So I know it gets all the data but it just doesn't return anything. It returns no load and or **oncanplay**.

Please can someone advise me on something I maybe doing wrong or a possible bug in Chrome.

```
function loadAudio(loc,after){
        window.itemsToLoad++;
        var aud = new Audio(loc);
        if(typeof(after)=="function"){
            aud.addEventListener('load', function () {updateLoaders();alert('Yes');after(aud);}, false);
        }else{
            aud.addEventListener('load', function () {alert('Yes');updateLoaders();},false);
        }
        aud.preload="none";
        aud.addEventListener('onerror', function () {alert('Error');updateErrorLoaders();},false);
        aud.addEventListener('onabort', function () {alert('abort');updateErrorLoaders();},false);
        aud.addEventListener('onemptied', function () {alert('empty');updateErrorLoaders();},false);
        aud.type="type=\"audio/ogg\"";
        aud.controls="controls";
        aud.load();
        return aud;
    }
window.imageBackground = loadImage('images/background2.png',function (img) { alert("Yes it bloody works ;)");});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed a few problems with your code. First, you define a `loadAudio` function but you are actually calling `loadImage('images/background2.png', fn)`. I assume this was just a slip up when you copy and pasted your code. Secondly, the `<audio>` element doesn't support the `type` attribute. If you want to specify the media type then use a child `<source>` element. Lastly, you are listening to the wrong event. Audio elements don't respond to the `onload` event, instead use the `onloadeddata` event. Here's your code with the updates and a little extension to support a callback that will be called when the audio has finished playing:

```
function updateLoaders() {
    // do stuff
}

function updateErrorLoaders() {
    // do stuff
}

function loadAudio(src, loadComplete, playComplete) {
    window.itemsToLoad++;
    var audio = new Audio();

    // Playback has completed.
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        if (typeof playComplete === 'function') {
            playComplete(audio);
        }
    }, false);
    // The entire song has loaded (not necessarily done playing).
    audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
        updateLoaders();

        if (typeof loadComplete === 'function') {
            loadComplete(audio);
        }
    }, false);

    // Handle errors.
    audio.addEventListener('error', function () {
        console.log('error');
        updateErrorLoaders();
    }, false);
    audio.addEventListener('abort', function () {
        console.log('abort');
        updateErrorLoaders();
    }, false);
    audio.addEventListener('emptied', function () {
        console.log('empty');
        updateErrorLoaders();
    }, false);

    audio.preload = 'none';
    audio.src = src;
    audio.controls = 'controls';
    audio.load();

    return audio;
}

var audio = loadAudio('Example.ogg', function (audio) {
    console.log('audio completely loaded');
    audio.play();
});
```

For more details on the events supported by `<audio>` elements see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp).